# _iob_func and VS 2015 porting of third party libraries with no source code

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am porting a project from VS2013 to VS2015. It links with a third party library `Y.lib` statically. Unfortunately, we do not have source code of this library.

In final linking stage, i get linker error as

```
unresolved external symbol __iob_func in X.lib"
```

where `X` uses `Y.lib`.

[Breaking changes documentation of VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx) states that :

`If the library is a third-party library for which source is not available, you should either request an updated binary from the third party or encapsulate your usage of that library into a separate DLL that you compile with the older version of the Visual C++ compiler and libraries.`

So, my question is whether their is some other workaround that people facing the same problem have figured out ?